# multiple meshes for rigged character

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

My character has so many meshes for it, 6 for the limbs, 4 for the hands/feet, and 2 for the body. I added 6 for the limbs due to my previous animation problem. Is this ok?

Comment: It may make the parent with automatic weights more difficult but you can correct afterwards

Comment: so it's fine, but what if it's for a unity game

Comment: It's not a problem, for example you can import a character with pants and vest in Unity, these are separate meshes within the same object, you can also use separate objects